# Enforce struct size alignment

Tags: c, memory-alignment, c11

Is there a way to force the size of a struct to be a multiple of the maximum required alignment for any type? Here are two different attempts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdalign.h>

typedef struct {
    char c;
} Block1;

typedef struct {
    char c;
    max_align_t data[];
} Block2;

typedef struct {
    char c;
    _Alignas(sizeof(max_align_t)) max_align_t data[];
} Block3;

int
main() {
    printf("sizeof(max_align_t): %zu\n", sizeof(max_align_t));
    printf("sizeof(Block1): %zu\n", sizeof(Block1));
    printf("sizeof(Block2): %zu\n", sizeof(Block2));
    printf("sizeof(Block3): %zu\n", sizeof(Block3));
}
```

With gcc 4.9.2 on a 64-bit machine I get this, so `Block3` seems to work. Interestingly, `Block2` does not work, though I can guess why:

```
sizeof(max_align_t): 32
sizeof(Block1): 1
sizeof(Block2): 16
sizeof(Block3): 32
```

Just wondering whether or not `Block3` is guaranteed to work (by the C11 standard), and whether or not there is a better way.

ADDENDUM: Apparently, I misinterpreted the meaning of `max_align_t`. I thought that `sizeof(max_align_t)` gives the maximum required alignment of any scalar type, but apparently it's `_Alignof(max_align_t)` that gives this. So `Block2` actually works.

Comment: There is a bit of overlap with the other question, but the goal is different. `_Alignas` is just a means here, and it's fine if there is a solution that doesn't apply it to member. Not that it matters that much, but it's probably worth reporting in the other question that missing `_Alignas` on members has been reported as a defect and will likely be fixed in the next TC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to force the size of a struct to be a multiple of the maximum required alignment?

Well, if you meant the maximum alignment for its elements, that's always trivially the case. You are done.

If instead you mean some *fundamental alignment*,

1. use `_Alignas(type)` on a member (you cannot accidentally lower the alignment-requirements this way).
2. use a member of a type aligned like above. Your second example uses a flexible-array-member doing so.

`max_align_t` has the maximum fundamental alignment.

If instead you mean some *extended alignment*, `_Alignas(power_of_two)` is your friend (unsupported alignments must be diagnosed), though there is no guarantee over-aligned types are supported at all.
Nor is there any way to query the maximum supported extended alignment.

> #### 6.2.8 Alignment of objects
>
> 1 Complete object types have alignment requirements which place restrictions on the addresses at which objects of that type may be allocated. An alignment is an
>   implementation-defined integer value representing the number of bytes between
>   successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated. An object type imposes an alignment requirement on every object of that type: stricter alignment can be requested using the `_Alignas` keyword.
>   2 A *fundamental alignment* is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to `_Alignof (max_align_t)`.
>   3 An *extended alignment* is represented by an alignment greater than `_Alignof (max_align_t)`. It is implementation-defined whether any extended alignments are supported and the contexts in which they are supported. A type having an extended alignment requirement is an *over-aligned* type.57)
>   4 Alignments are represented as values of the type `size_t`. Valid alignments include only those values returned by an `_Alignof` expression for fundamental types, plus an additional implementation-defined set of values, which may be empty. Every valid alignment value shall be a nonnegative integral power of two.
>   5 Alignments have an order from *weaker* to *stronger* or *stricter* alignments. Stricter alignments have larger alignment values. An address that satisfies an alignment requirement also satisfies any weaker valid alignment requirement.
>   6 The alignment requirement of a complete type can be queried using an `_Alignof` expression. The types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` shall have the weakest alignment requirement.
>   7 Comparing alignments is meaningful and provides the obvious results:
>
> - Two alignments are equal when their numeric values are equal.
> - Two alignments are different when their numeric values are not equal.
> - When an alignment is larger than another it represents a stricter alignment.

Comment: I mean, force the size of a struct to be a multiple of `sizeof(max_align_t)`.

Comment: I listed two ways, one of which you used.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that I have misinterpreted the meaning of `max_align_t`. Apparently, `sizeof(max_align_t)` is NOT the maximum required alignment of any scalar type. Rather, `_Alignof(max_align_t)` is. So the `Block2` struct does it, and `Block3` is actually larger than necessary. I guess one might assume that `sizeof(max_align_t) == _Alignof(max_align_t)`, but this appears to not necessarily be true.

Comment: That's right. Anyway, I wonder why you felt the need not to use the type directly in `_Alignas`.